# Using define_method to generate dynamic array names in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I'm trying to figure out how to use define_method (or any other method) to generate array names as my method loops through an array and converts each hash element to JSON. Right now, my data is a series of hash arrays just dumped into a file, not contained in any larger array.

```
data_arrays = [{"key1":"value1"}, {"key2":"value2"}]
       [{"key3":"value3"}, ("key4":"value4")]
       [{"key5":"value5"}, ("key6":"value6")]
```

The code I was trying to work with is something like the following. Basically, I want each hash array to be converted into JSON and be assigned a new name, like json_array_1, jason_array_2, etc.

```
data_arrays.each do |element|
    for (i = 0; i < data_array.length; i+=1) do
        define_method("json_array_#{i}") do
            json_array_[i] = element.to_json
        end
    end
end
```

I'm aware this line: `for (i = 0; i < data_array.length; i+=1) do` is not really Ruby or good code at all. But I needed a way to iterate through the loop while also making the variable "i" available to be inserted in the json_array names. Can anyone give me any pointers for getting this code to work? I'm probably overthinking things and making this harder than it actually is.

Comment: You haven't presented your problem clear enough so I can only help with little things.
(1) To get array index use `data_arrays.each_with_index do |element, i|`
(2) To call a method dynamically use `send("json_array_#{i}=", element.to_json)`

Comment: Your definition of `data_arrays` has several errors. See how I defined it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
data_arrays.each_with_index do |element, i|
  define_method("json_array_#{i}") do
    element.to_json
  end
end
```

This will define methods `json_array_0`, `json_array_1`...
Make it `"json_array_#{i + 1}"`if you want to start from `json_array_1.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, this doesn't seem to be working at all for me. Nothing actually runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
data_arrays = [[{key1:"value1"}, {key2:"value2"}],
               [{key3:"value3"}, {key4:"value4"}],
               [{key5:"value5"}, {key6:"value6"}]]
require 'json'

json_strings = data_arrays.map { |a| a.map { |h| h.to_json } }
  #=> [["{\"key1\":\"value1\"}", "{\"key2\":\"value2\"}"],
  #    ["{\"key3\":\"value3\"}", "{\"key4\":\"value4\"}"],
  #    ["{\"key5\":\"value5\"}", "{\"key6\":\"value6\"}"]]

or

json_strings = data_arrays.flat_map { |a| a.map { |h| h.to_json } }
  #=> ["{\"key1\":\"value1\"}", "{\"key2\":\"value2\"}", "{\"key3\":\"value3\"}", 
  #    "{\"key4\":\"value4\"}", "{\"key5\":\"value5\"}", "{\"key6\":\"value6\"}"] 

depending on your needs.
```

Comment: I see that you place data_arrays inside its own larger array. However, I'm working with a file that is generated as three separate hash arrays, no commas in between. When I try pushing the hash arrays into a larger array, I always keep ending up with strings. I'm not really sure why this is happening, although I agree it would be a lot easier if data_arrays was already contained with a larger array.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying those are text strings in a file? If so, please edit your answer to say so and put the strings in quotes. Also,it makes no sense to set `data_arrays` to something that is not a Ruby object.